# Mismatch between plots and data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Okay, i have TotalBags and year column, so i'm trying to visualize and knowing the TotalBags saled in each year so i create `yearlySales = avo_sales.groupby(['year'])['TotalBags'].sum()` to plot `plt.plot(yearlySales)` and also i plot with seaborn (because i'm kind of curious if both returns same plot shape) with `sns.lineplot(avo_sales.year,avo_sales.TotalBags)` There are several issues i found

1. The seaborn lineplot and my regular plot returns different shape of plot, what did i do wrong? why is it like this?
   [image: seaborn line plot][image: plt regular plot]
2. The plot does not shape like the data, it should be from 7-1-1-4 (7-down-straight-up), why does both plots mismatch with the data? what causing it?

```
yearlySales
Out[20]: 
year
2015    7.721922e+08
2016    1.463159e+09
2017    1.646289e+09
2018    4.915359e+08
Name: TotalBags, dtype: float64
```

3. How can yearlySales totals is xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx when in each year it only totals x.x

```
avo_sales.TotalBags.sum()
Out[24]: 4373175798.389999
```

Comment: You should look on numbers notation. 7.721922e+08 means 7.721..x10^8 and 1.463159e+09 is 1.4631..x10^9, so it equal 14.63159e+08.

Comment: oh okay thank you for you comments it helps me, but why does the plot shape not goes down at the end because at 2018 there's decreasing for the seaborn lineplot? does that mean that the 'correct' plot for now is the regular plot? @Alexey

Comment: because the 4.9*10^8 is the lowest point from your list:  7.72*10^8, 14.63*10^8, 16.46*10^8, 4.91*10^8
It looks like that on your first plot you show accumulated result